# Detect program launch in another thread on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, chroot, ptrace

I am trying to sandbox ELF binaries by (among other things) chrooting them after they have been launched. To do so, a child process cloned with the CLONE_FS tag performs a chroot, while the parent runs the binary by calling an exec function.

The trick actually works if the chroot happens after the program has finished loading the shared libraries it needs. The problem is that I can't find a way to detect when this actually happens from the other process. Is there any way?

Comment: Why not use a dynamic library instead? A function marked [`__attribute__ ((constructor (65535)))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconstructor_007d-function-attribute-2853) will be automatically executed just prior to `main()`, and you can use the [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) environment variable to load it. Usually you'd also write a small binary, that sets the environment variables for the preload library, then executes the sandboxed binary. No extra processes needed, either.

Comment: Nice trick! This is a very good answer indeed. Though I think I still prefer to use an extra process due to the privileges chroot needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a preload library with a function executed just prior to `main()`, a helper binary with `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` permitted filesystem capability, and an Unix domain socket pair between the two.

The helper binary creates the socket pair, then uses `clone(CLONE_FS)` to fork a helper process that shares the file system information, sets `LD_PRELOAD` to load the preload library, and executes the sandboxed binary. (`exec` resets the capabilities per the sandboxed binary filesystem capabilities, so the sandboxed binary will not have any extra privileges at all.)

The helper process adds `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` to the effective set, waits for the sandboxed binary (preload library) to notify it via the socket, calls `chroot()`, and notifies the sandboxed binary (preload library) of success.

Note: There is absolutely no need to mark the helper binary setuid root, or to give the sandboxed binary any capabilities or privileges. We can do this with minimal privileges: [`CAP_SYS_CHROOT` capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) is sufficient.

I prefer to add the capability to the binary only into the permitted set, so that the binary itself has to add the capability to the effective set before `chroot()` works. I feel this approach reduces the effects of possible installation/administrator errors. If you disagree, feel free to omit the corresponding code from `exec.c`, and use `=pe` instead of `=p` in the `setcap` command in Makefile.

The neat thing here is that the preload library could also interpose desired C functions, and use the unix domain socket to obtain the necessary information from the helper process; you can even use [`SCM_RIGHTS`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) ancillary messages to transfer file descriptors from outside the chroot to the sandboxed binary. (In essence, this is what [`fakeroot`](http://fakeroot.alioth.debian.org/) does, but in reverse: instead of faking a chrooted environment, you can pick and choose which files the sandboxed binary can access from outside the chroot environment.) Just have the helper process stay alive as long as the other end of the socket is still open, so it'll exit after the sandboxed binary exits.

Here is my example implementation that starts the helper process as a child process to the sandboxed binary, with the helper process exiting (and preload library reaping it) before the sandboxed `main()` is started.

**exec.c**:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef  SOCKET_FD
#error SOCKET_FD not defined!
#endif

#ifndef  LIBRARY_PATH
#error LIBRARY_PATH not defined!
#endif

static size_t            helper_stack_size = 32768;
static void             *helper_stack = NULL;
static const char       *helper_chroot = NULL;
static const cap_value_t helper_cap[] = { CAP_SYS_CHROOT };
static const int         helper_caps = sizeof helper_cap / sizeof helper_cap[0];
static int               socket_fd[2] = { -1, -1 };

#ifdef __hppa
#define helper_endstack  (helper_stack)
#else
#define helper_endstack  ((void *)((char *)helper_stack + helper_stack_size - 1))
#endif

static int helper_main(void *arg)
{
    const char *const argv0 = arg;
    pid_t pid;
    cap_t caps;

    close(socket_fd[0]);

    /* Read the target PID. */
    {   char       *p = (char *)(&pid);
        char *const q = (char *)(&pid) + sizeof pid;
        ssize_t     n;

        while (p < q) {
            n = recv(socket_fd[1], p, (size_t)(q - p), MSG_WAITALL);
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(EIO));
                return 127;
            } else
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(errno));
                return 127;
            }
        }
    }

    if (pid < (pid_t)2) {
        shutdown(socket_fd[1], SHUT_RDWR);
        close(socket_fd[1]);
        return 127;
    }

    /* Enable CAP_SYS_CHROOT. */
    caps = cap_get_proc();
    if (cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_EFFECTIVE, helper_caps, helper_cap, CAP_SET)) {
        shutdown(socket_fd[1], SHUT_RDWR);
        close(socket_fd[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(errno));
        return 127;
    }
    if (cap_set_proc(caps)) {
        shutdown(socket_fd[1], SHUT_RDWR);
        close(socket_fd[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(errno));
        return 127;
    }

    /* Target is ready to be chrooted, so do it now. */
    if (chroot(helper_chroot)) {
        shutdown(socket_fd[1], SHUT_RDWR);
        close(socket_fd[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot chroot: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(errno));
        return 127;
    }

    /* Send my own pid, so this process will be reaped. */
    {   const char       *p = (char *)(&pid);
        const char *const q = (char *)(&pid) + sizeof pid;
        ssize_t           n;

        pid = getpid();

        while (p < q) {
            n = send(socket_fd[1], p, (size_t)(q - p), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(EIO));
                return 127;
            } else
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(errno));
                return 127;
            }
        }
    }

    /* We won't be sending anything else. */
    shutdown(socket_fd[1], SHUT_WR);

    /* Ignore further input; wait for other end to close descriptor. */
    {   char    buf[16];
        ssize_t n;

        while (1) {
            n = recv(socket_fd[1], buf, sizeof buf, 0);
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                continue;
            else
            if (n == (ssize_t)0)
                break;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(EIO));
                return 127;
            } else
            if (errno == EPIPE)
                break;
            else
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv0, strerror(errno));
                return 127;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Close the socket, and exit. */
    shutdown(socket_fd[1], SHUT_RDWR);
    close(socket_fd[1]);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (argc < 4 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s CHROOT WORKDIR COMMAND [ ARGS ... ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Note: . is a valid WORKDIR.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (chdir(argv[2])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[2], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    helper_stack = mmap(NULL, helper_stack_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                              MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_STACK | MAP_GROWSDOWN, -1, (off_t)0);
    if ((void *)helper_stack == MAP_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create helper process stack: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    helper_chroot = argv[1];

    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket_fd)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create an Unix domain stream socket pair: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if (clone(helper_main, helper_endstack, CLONE_FS, argv[0]) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot clone a helper process: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        close(socket_fd[0]);
        close(socket_fd[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    close(socket_fd[1]);
    if (socket_fd[0] != SOCKET_FD) {
        if (dup2(socket_fd[0], SOCKET_FD) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot move stream socket: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
            close(socket_fd[0]);
            close(SOCKET_FD);
            return 1;
        }
        close(socket_fd[0]);
    }

    setenv("LD_PRELOAD", LIBRARY_PATH, 1);

    /* Capabilities are reset over an execve(). */
    execvp(argv[3], argv + 3);

    close(SOCKET_FD);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[3], strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

**premain.c**:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef SOCKET_FD
#error SOCKET_FD is not defined!
#endif

static void init(void) __attribute__ ((constructor (65535)));

static void init(void)
{
    pid_t pid;

    /* Note: We could probably only remove libpremain.so
     *       from the value, instead of clearing it altogether. */
    unsetenv("LD_PRELOAD");

    /* Verify SOCKFD is an Unix domain socket. */
    {   struct sockaddr_un  addr;
        socklen_t           addrlen = sizeof addr;
        memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);

        errno = EIO;
        if (getsockname(SOCKET_FD, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen))
            switch (errno) {

            case EBADF:
                /* SOCKET_FD is not open. Continue as if libpremain.so was never loaded. */
                errno = 0;
                return;

            case ENOTSOCK:
                /* SOCKET_FD is not a socket. Continue as if libpremain.so was never loaded. */
                errno = 0;
                return;

            default:
                /* All other errors are fatal. */
                exit(127);
            }

        if (addr.sun_family != AF_UNIX) {
            /* SOCKET_FD is not an Unix domain socket. Continue as if libpremain.so was never loaded. */
            errno = 0;
            return;
        }
    }

    /* Make SOCKET_FD blocking and close-on-exec. */
    if (fcntl(SOCKET_FD, F_SETFD, (long)FD_CLOEXEC) ||
        fcntl(SOCKET_FD, F_SETFL, (long)0L))
        exit(127);

    /* Send our PID. */
    {   const char       *p = (const char *)(&pid);
        const char *const q = (const char *)(&pid) + sizeof pid;

        pid = getpid();

        while (p < q) {
            ssize_t n = send(SOCKET_FD, p, (size_t)(q - p), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1)
                exit(127);
            else
            if (errno != EINTR)
                exit(127);
        }
    }

    /* Receive the PID from the other end. */
    {   char       *p = (char *)(&pid);
        char *const q = (char *)(&pid) + sizeof pid;

        pid = (pid_t)-1;

        while (p < q) {
            ssize_t n = recv(SOCKET_FD, p, (size_t)(q - p), MSG_WAITALL);
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1)
                exit(127);
            else
            if (errno != EINTR)
                exit(127);
        }
    }

    shutdown(SOCKET_FD, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(SOCKET_FD);

    /* If the PID is > 1, we wait for it to exit.
     * If an error occurs, it's not a problem. */
    if (pid > (pid_t)1) {
        pid_t p;
        do {
            p = waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        } while (p == (pid_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
    }

    /* All done. */
    return;
}
```

**Makefile**:

```
CC  := gcc
CFLAGS  := -Wall -O3
LD  := $(CC)
LDFLAGS := -lcap

PREFIX  := /usr
BINDIR  := $(PREFIX)/bin
LIBDIR  := $(PREFIX)/lib

SOCKFD  := 15

.PHONY: all clean

all: clean libpremain.so exec-chroot

clean:
    rm -f libpremain.so exec-chroot

libpremain.so: premain.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DSOCKET_FD=$(SOCKFD) -fPIC -shared $^ -ldl -Wl,-soname,$@ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

exec-chroot: exec.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DSOCKET_FD=$(SOCKFD) -DLIBRARY_PATH='"'$(LIBDIR)/libpremain.so'"' $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

install: libpremain.so exec-chroot
    sudo rm -f $(LIBDIR)/libpremain.so $(BINDIR)/exec-chroot
    sudo install -o `id -un` -g `id -gn` -m 00770 libpremain.so $(LIBDIR)/libpremain.so
    sudo install -o `id -un` -g `id -gn` -m 00770 exec-chroot $(BINDIR)/exec-chroot
    sudo setcap 'cap_sys_chroot=p' $(BINDIR)/exec-chroot

uninstall:
    sudo rm -f $(LIBDIR)/libpremain.so $(BINDIR)/exec-chroot
```

Note that the indentation in the Makefile is with <kbd>tab</kbd>s, not spaces. Run

```
make PREFIX=/usr/local clean install
```

to compile and install to `/usr/local`, but only executable by the current user. You can also use `clean all` to only recompile everything, or `uninstall` to uninstall the binaries.`

This does require the [`libcap`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/) library. It is maintained as part of the kernel, but you might need to install a `libcap-dev` or `libcap-devel` or similarly-named package to get all the necessary files to compile against it.

After installing, you can run e.g.

```
exec-chroot /tmp /tmp ls -alF /
```

to run `ls -alF /` in `/tmp` chrooted to `/tmp`. The output on Ubuntu machines is typically something like

```
drwxrwxrwt 11    0    0  4096 May 29 23:55 ./
drwxrwxrwt 11    0    0  4096 May 29 23:55 ../
drwxrwxrwt  2    0    0  4096 May 29 17:15 .ICE-unix/
-r--r--r--  1    0    0    11 May 29 17:15 .X0-lock
drwxrwxrwt  2    0    0  4096 May 29 17:15 .X11-unix/
drwx------  2 1000 1000  4096 May 29 17:15 .esd-1000/
drwx------  2    0    0 16384 Dec  2  2011 lost+found/
drwx------  2 1000 1000  4096 May 29 17:15 pulse-xxxxxxxxx/
drwx------  2    0    0  4096 May 29 17:15 pulse-yyyyyyyyy/
```

where the owner and group are 0 (root) and 1000 (user), respectively, because the passwd and group databases are inaccessible from within the chroot. However, as I already mentioned, it can be worked around by modifying and extending the above code as outlined.

Although I did try to write the code with careful error handling, I have not really considered the overall operation thoroughly with respect to error conditions or security issues; that is why the files are installed only accessible to the current user.

Questions?

Comment: Impressive! Thanks to your hint, I came up with a similar solution, although I'm sending simple messages instead of pids. Any reason for the pids?

Comment: @twicker: Well, no reason, really.. except that the library uses the second one (the one it receives) to reap the helper process. Simple one-character messages will work just as well, if the library does not reap the helper process (for example, if helper process stays alive as long as the socket is open). If you do interpose `open()` et al, you can use raw binary messages (use structs, with first member defining the message length, and second the message type) much the same way as the pids are sent and received, since the socket is local: there can be no byte order or format issues.